# In chess engines where bitboards are used, how are the edges detected?

Tags: c++, chess, bitboard

For example, all white pawns' attacks are either generated by shifting 7 or 9 bits to the left (or right, I could be mistaken, but I think it's easy to get the gist).

So the white pawn bitboard that looks like this

`00000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111100000000`

Would be shifted into this

`00000000000000000000000000000001111111100000000000000000`

However, if you attempt to portray this example in a 8x8 array, one of the pawns goes through the chessboard's edge.

So when the bits are shifted to generate attacks, how do the engines prevent themselves from generating ones that go through the chessboard's edges?

Comment: Done! Yeah, I think so (?), but still, one of the answers below has already helped me!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We'll add some whitespace.  Suppose you start with a pawn position:

```
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
10000000
01100101
00011010
00000000
00000000
```

The newlines are just there for ease of reading, everything is packed bits.  Where can the pawns move?

```
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
10000000
01100101
00011010
00000000
00000000
00000000
```

here, the only risk of going past an edge is at the top, which is easy to deal with.

Next, where can the pawns take?  The naive solution is you take the above "move" mask, and shift it left and right 1.  As you noticed, this causes wraparound.

```
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000001
00000000
11001010
00110100
00000000
00000000
00000000
|
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
01000000
00110010
10001101
00000000
00000000
00000000
```

(apologies if you dislike my choice of endianness).

We can fix this with some masking.  The bits that will wrap around are at known locations.  So we mask them out before we do the operation.

This mask:

```
11111110
11111110
11111110
11111110
11111110
11111110
11111110
11111110
```

before we shift right, and

```
01111111
01111111
01111111
01111111
01111111
01111111
01111111
01111111
```

before we shift left.

So to see the spots threatened by pawns, where "forward" is a right shift, we do:

```
auto pawn_moves = pawn_mask >> 8;
auto pawn_left_take = (pawn_moves & not_left_column) << 1;
auto pawn_right_take = (pawn_moves & not_right_column) << 1;
auto pawn_take = pawn_left_take | pawn_right_take;
```

and there we have it.

Similar masking can be done for other cases.  For example, if we are calculating the knight take mask we need 8 masks and 8 shifts, then or them all together.

For a rook moving right 3, you mask out the right 3 columns, then do a right 3 shift on the rook mask.

At some point, however, you are likely to want to use intrinsics and SIMD processing; so the exact bit operations you have that are fast are going to depend on your handware.  Maybe unpacking 8 8 bit values into 8 24 bit values, doing your mask-free operation there, then extracting the middle 8 bits is the fastest way on your particular hardware.

Comment: This is exactly what I've been searching for. For some reason, I thought that bitboards alone would solve the problem of pieces attacking through edges (until I implemented them).

Thanks, really! You really helped me.

Comment: For rooks, vertical is `|` every line together, horizonal is `y=((x>>8)-x & column_1)`, then `y-(y<<8)` I think.  (first "moves" the rook to column 1, second smears it over the row.  Probably has off-by-one errors)